# Calling an overloaded method from an anonymous, generic class in Java

Tags: java, overloading, anonymous-class

I'm trying to create an extended version of a `DefaultListModel` (of type `String`) that accepts an object of a class I've created, called a `LogItem` and 'automatically' use that information to infer what data should be used to populate the relevant element.

In my code it looks like this:

```
public static DefaultListModel<String> log = new DefaultListModel<String>(){

    public void addElement(LogItem logItem){

        super.addElement("[" + logItem.getTimestamp() + "] " + logItem.getEvent());

    }

};
```

and later in the class:

```
log.addElement(new LogItem(event));
```

Yet the latter of those two sections of code gives a compile-time error:

```
Error:(196, 32) java: incompatible types: com.example.LogItem cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

So it appears as if I, for some reason, cannot access the overloaded method I made in the anonymous class (`addElement(LogItem logitem){...}`).

I guess I must be missing something, why can't I use the overloaded class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

You could use a method to get the string representation of your logItem and pass it to your DefaultListModel:

```
private String getLogItemAsString(LogItem logItem) {
    return "[" + logItem.getTimestamp() + "] " + logItem.getEvent();
}
```

then

```
log.addElement(getLogItemAsString(new LogItem(event)));
```

Maybe a nicer way to do this would be through a Utility Class:

```
public final class DefaultListModelUtils {

    private DefaultListModelUtils() {}

    public static final void addElement(DefaultListModel<String> defaultListModel, LogItem logItem) {
        defaultListModel.addElement(getLogItemAsString(logItem));
    }

    private static String getLogItemAsString(LogItem logItem) {
        return "[" + logItem.getTimestamp() + "] " + logItem.getEvent();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
DefaultListModelUtils.addElement(log, new LogItem(event));
```

Or you can extend `DefaultListModel<String>` like this:

```
public class MyDefaultListModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {
    public void addElement(LogItem logItem){
        super.addElement("[" + logItem.getTimestamp() + "] " + logItem.getEvent());
    }
}
```

then use

```
MyDefaultListModel log = new MyDefaultListModel();
log.addElement(new LogItem(event));
```

Comment: seems like option 1 is the way to go, since you don't seem to be able to change the declared type of `log`

Comment: Thank you! I used the third option. I just really wanted to add that _one_ overloaded method, and your solution works! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could also override the `toString()` method of you LogItem class, or implement another method for conversion if `toString()` is allready used:

```
public String toString() {
    return "[" + getTimestamp() + "] " + getEvent();
}
```

And then just use the regular `addElement(String)`:

```
log.addElement( (new LogItem(event)).toString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

The declared type of the variable determines what the compiler allows, not the runtime type. The declared type of your variable `log` is `DefaultListModel<String>`, which does not have a `void addElement(LogItem)` method. The compiler cannot allow a call to a method not known to the declared type. It can only find `void addElement(String)`. And you can't call that with a `LogItem` argument.

Comment: So how might I go about fixing this? Since I can't change the declared type without causing a number of other issues, what would be the best way to get this working?